# How to best override behavior of keyboard backlight key with new custom driver?

Tags: kernel

I am working on an embryo of a new platform driver for the Samsung Galaxybook in Linux which you can see [here](https://github.com/joshuagrisham/linux/blob/samsung-galaxybook/drivers/platform/x86/samsung-galaxybook.c). I have managed to successfully debug the kernel in Windows and able to piece together mostly how the Windows driver "Samsung System Event Controller" is working for a few scenarios, and the first one I am starting with is the Keyboard Backlight control.

There is an ACPI device which the driver in Windows grabs and then there is a generic "Settings" ACPI Method (CSFI) within that device that the driver is sending all kind of different payloads to in order to control certain things (kbd backlight, "performance mode", autostart when you open the lid, etc).

There are 3 different brightness levels for this keyboard backlight, and the payload which is sent to the ACPI method has a specific byte which is just given directly as 0, 1, 2, or 3. I have replicated this now for the keyboard backlight and it is working successfully on my laptop if I do something like this:

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/samsung-galaxybook::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

It is also picked up correctly by `brightnessctl` and other similar utilities, so that is a pretty good success!

```
sudo brightnessctl --device='samsung-galaxybook::kbd_backlight' set 3
Updated device 'samsung-galaxybook::kbd_backlight':
Device 'samsung-galaxybook::kbd_backlight' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 3 (100%)
    Max brightness: 3
```

Now on to the meat of the question:

There is a single key on the keyboard (fn+F9) where, in Windows, when you press it repeatedly, it cycles through the different levels in a circle (0,1,2,3,0,1,2,etc).

When you press this key in Linux then it seems to be coming through the normal keyboard device but is not a mapped key, and actually throws an error you can see in `dmesg` like this:

```
kernel: atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xac on isa0060/serio0).
kernel: atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02c <keycode>' to make it known.
```

I have tried to play around a bit with hwdb by for example creating a mapping for it like

- `KEYBOARD_KEY_ac=kbdillumtoggle`, which actually did control the backlight but would only "turn on" the backlight at max (3) and turn it off (0) with repeated presses -- there was no way to get to levels 1 and 2, and
- `KEYBOARD_KEY_ac=kbdillumup`, which "kind of" worked in that the very first time starting from 0, you were able to step up through 1, 2, and then 3. But once you hit the top, it would only stay on 3 at the top, and you could not turn the light off.

I guess I am at a bit of a cross-road here, as I do not know what the "right" solution is for this. What is the best way to actually try and map in this key so that I can control this new kbd backlight in the way that I want? Is it possible to build this into the platform driver somehow, where it will actually capture the keys and then I can write the code to control this "cycle" behavior?

I looked a bit into the sparse keymap support, but as I understand this is more for if your key is part of your ACPI device (it throws ACPI events when you press it instead of "normal" keyboard presses from your keyboard device??) which is not the case here -- my key actually does come in through the keyboard but I would want to sort of "override" its behavior somehow, and ideally in a "standardized" way that gives a good out-of-the-box experience combined with the new platform driver.

What are my options and what is the "best"/"right" option for this?